# sub('a*|b', '', 'bcd') -> bcd WAT?

Tags: python, regex

today I stumbled upon a weird behavior in regexp - matching. I cannot explain it, though I thought I am quite experienced with regexes

```
print re.sub('a*|b',  '', 'bcd')
```

> bcd

where without glob

```
print re.sub('a|b',  '', 'bcd')
```

> cd

that is expected. 
I thought failed alternative wouldn't prevent trying the others!

Comment: It looks like you want a `+` quantifier instead of `*`. Try `re.sub('a+|b',  '', 'bcd')`

Answer (score 7):

`a*` **always matches** (zero to infinite number of `a` characters).

So, you end up replacing at the location of the match - an `''` with `bcd`.

So the whole string returns.

---

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
>
> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl.

So, the start of the `''` string is an occurrence of zero `a`s and is replaced by `repl`.

Comment: ...so **b** is not even considered, because preceding **a*** matched zero times?

Comment: @YuryPaykov - correct. It really depends on the regex engine implementation whether it is evaluated/considered, but the first match is `a*`.

Comment: Great answer.  I just want to add that these problems are often easier to debug by using a replacement string you can see rather than the empty string, like `re.sub('a*|b', 'replaced', 'bcd')`.  That makes it clear the first part of the match isn't failing.

Comment: I'm still not sure why the replacement doesn't go through. `re.sub` is supposed to *all* non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern when `count` is zero. Eg. `re.sub('a|b', '*', 'abcdab')` produces `**cd**`. Why is the zero width match before `b` considered to overlap with `b`?